# There is a communication protocol between vehicles and Cloud?

Tags: network-protocols, telecommunication

I did not find the correct Stack for this question. If you have a more appropriate one to suggest, write it in the comments as well: if necessary, I will move the question into that Stack.

I would like to know if there are special communication protocols between vehicle and cloud. I'm not talking about 802.11p or the use of cellular networks, but I would like to know about the communication protocols dedicated to vehicles, to say HTTPS or MQTT do not seem really usable for connecting on-board computers and the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Vehicle communications are usually broken down into:

- Vehicle to vehicle/environment - local communication to other vehicles, traffic signals, even pedestrians close by
- Vehicle to Internet communication

You are asking primarily about the second one - my experience is that much (most?) vehicle to internet, or to manufacturers networks via the internet, builds on standard IP based communication, generally leveraging security mechanisms such as HTTPS as you suggest.

The security angle is obviously very key and there is quite a bit of research and innovation in this domain. It is a feature not only at automotive shows and conferences but also at IT security shows like BlackHat where you will find cybersecurity companies displaying connected vehicle security solutions.